# Which cosmological dark matter theory is most compatible with current particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter

This occurred to me while I was writing [Why hasn't warm dark matter replaced cold dark matter as the standard model of cosmology?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128125/why-hasnt-warm-dark-matter-replaced-cold-dark-matter-as-the-standard-model-of-c) but I think this deserves a question of its own. The background info for this question is covered in that link, so I'll just cut straight to the point.

Is one of the current cosmological dark matter models of interest (cold dark matter, warm dark matter, self-interacting cold/warm dark matter) easier to reconcile with our current understanding of particle physics and the current measured limits on possible undiscovered particles?

Comment: "current understanding of particle physics" what makes you think we currently understand particle physics ?

Comment: @ticster We certainly don't understand everything, but we also understand more than nothing!

Comment: Right you are ;) It was just my witty way of pointing out that your answer clearly lies beyond the standard model, so it's not so much about "what we understand" and more about "what we could understand were it to be the case". Dark matter models are made "sexier" by the problems they *could* resolve, not by the ones we've already understood. Which is why there are probably about as many dark matter candidates as there are open questions in particle physics.

Answer (score 3):

Each model of dark matter has its strengths and weaknesses in different regimes. Sterile neutrinos are compelling since they can explain neutrino oscillation and dark matter. Warm dark matter closes some of the gaps between simulated and observed galaxy dynamics and properties. Cold dark matter doesn't require an emission line from annihilation since it has not been observed yet (except for 3.5 keV line). The evidence is not overwhelming for either case as of now.

Answer (score 2):

> easier to reconcile with our current understanding of particle physics and the current measured limits on possible undiscovered particles?

Dark matter whether cold or hot or lukewarm needs frontier particle physics research, i.e. beyond the standard model, which is our current understanding. All theories can be accommodated within present limits,  as long as the LHC does not produce a supersymmetric candidate (the next level of sought after *standard physics*) to nail down a [WIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles), necessary as a candidate for dark matter.